# Can every cohomology class be represented by an analytic form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, hodge-theory, de-rham-cohomology

Let $M$ be an analytic manifold (you may assume it is equipped with an analytic metric). Must each De Rham cohomology class be representatble by an analytic differential form ?

I think Hodge theory maybe relevant here but I can't judge as I don't know if harmonic forms are necessarily analytic or not

Thank you

Comment: Yes, if you assume that $M$ is compact. Indeed each harmonic form with respect to a real-analytic metric is real-analytic. This is a consequence of the Cauchy-Kovalevsky theorem, for instance. I do not know about the noncompact case.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  That's nice to know, where is compactness being used in your argument ?

Comment: Maybe not, but Hodge theorem I know requires compactness or integrability.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Aha I see. Thank you